# Eav Model relationship

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav

I am trying to create an eav attribute model. I create one for blog its working good as long as it has individual entity.

Now my question is how I can implement relationships using eav model.
for example I have a table name theme which have ( themeId, themeName, themeImage) now I have another table which have product related to theme it looks like ( productId, productName, productImage, productDescription, fkThemeId )

```
   <resources>
        <planner_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Opco_Planner</module>
                <class>Opco_Planner_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </planner_setup>
    </resources>
```

and installer looks like

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addEntityType('planner_theme', array(
 ..............
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

How we can create multiple table along with resource setup and how we manage relationship are define above.

link or help in any way will be highly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: by relationship you mean a many to many relationship or one to many? I mean your theme should have multiple products associated to it and a product should have multiple themes? Or how should it work?

Comment: In my case it will one to many but for understanding both because in future I might need it.

Comment: And how are your entities EAV since you have tables for each one of them with a field per attribute?

Comment: I have no idea how I am going to implement it. After creating first table these table were created

planner_theme
planner_theme_char
planner_theme_datetime
planner_theme_decimal
planner_theme_int
planner_theme_text
planner_theme_varchar

with attribute as I mentioned above ( themeId, themeName, themeImage ) now I am planing to create another one with relationship but have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to create a CRUD module with 2 entities and a relation between them, I can recommend the [Ultimate Module Creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9).
It should get you started (even more than that).
It allows you to create your entities just like you would create a table using PhpMyAdmin.
it allows you to decide between flat and EAV entities and even combine them in a single module.
It allows you to establish relations between your entities as many to many or one to many.
If you need a relation to products or categories, it handles that also.
Then you have to install the generated code over your magento instance.
**Never use directly on production.** 
The documentation can be [found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki).

<sub>I am involved in the development of the recommended extension but the extension is free and I get no financial benefits out of it.</sub>

Comment: Actually I want to understand how it works. No doubt extension is great. What if I create theme entity and now I want to add products to my theme like i did with configurable product how I am able to do it.

Comment: after creating model using your extension I am unable to access any controller every request end up with 404 page. In controller I have ( ThemeController, DecorationController ) with viewAction method. I try access it with "http://localsite/planner/theme/view" I am getting 404 error page.

Comment: are you trying to access the frontend or backend controller?

Comment: I am trying to access fronted controller. Please also I need your comment on my first comment as well.

Comment: for the view action in the frontend controller you need to specify a valid id `planner/theme/view/id/3`. For associating the products in a many to many relation with your theme you should see a separate tab when adding/editing a theme.